# Why this problem when showing the heatmap with Plotly?

Tags: python, plotly, heatmap

I want to create a simple annoted heatmap with plotly.
But I get something strange when the y values contains years ('2017','2018','2019')

for example:

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

# create a x list (month)
x = ['January',
     'February',
     'March']

#create a y list (year)
y=['2017', '2018', '2019', 'Mean']

#create a z list (the values)
z = [[1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9],
    [4,5,6]]

fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(z,x=x,y=y)
fig.show()
```

this code above give me this result :[image]

But, if I change the y list with other string. il's ok and I get what I want.

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

# create a x list (month)
x = ['January',
     'February',
     'March']

#create a y list (year)
y=['year 1', 'year 2', 'year 3', 'Mean']

#create a z list (the values)
z = [[1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9],
    [4,5,6]]

fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(z,x=x,y=y)
fig.show()
```

[image]

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `fig.update_layout(yaxis=dict(type='category'))`. This should ensure that the values on the y-axis are interpreted as strings.

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

# create a x list (month)
x = ['January',
     'February',
     'March']

#create a y list (year)
y=['2017', '2018', '2019', 'Mean']

#create a z list (the values)
z = [[1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9],
    [4,5,6]]

fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(z,x=x,y=y)

fig.update_layout(yaxis=dict(type='category'))

fig.show()
```

Comment: I get the the same broken result with the sample code as OP. Interestingly, neither `fig.update_layout(yaxis=dict(type='category'))` nor `fig.update_yaxes(type='category')` do solve this issue in my case. Instead, all colored boxes are not drawn anymore. What Plotly version did you use? (Tested with Plotly 4.12.0 and Plotly 5.1.0 on Python 3.7.6)

Comment: I don't remember which version of Plotly I was using at the time, but I have just rerun the code (I have Plotly 5.3.1) and indeed it doesn't work anymore.